# Do I need to apply to the same country each time to get a multi year multiple entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry

According to the [EU Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202) (Article 24, paragraph 2), on granting multiple entry visas:

> (a) for a validity period of one year, provided that the applicant has
> obtained and lawfully used three visas within the previous two years;
>
> (b) for a validity period of two years, provided that the applicant
> has obtained and lawfully used a previous multiple-entry visa valid
> for one year within the previous two years;
>
> of five years, provided that the applicant has obtained and lawfully
> used a previous multiple-entry visa valid for two years within the
> previous three years.(c) for a validity period

I'm wondering if all the "visas" mentioned in this article need to be of the same country. For instance, if I have had a Schengen C visa (<1 month each) from Switzerland, Germany and Denmark in the last two years, can I apply for a 1 year multi-entry visa from either of these consulates?

Comment: Yes, since they all use the same VIS database for visa applications.

Comment: How do you "apply" for a 1 year (or any other period) visa? There is no such an option in Schengen visa application.